# Servidor Xampp nao acessa pelo meu ip

Tags: php, servidor, xampp

Tenho o servidor XAMPP instalado ja configurei ele para listem 8080 e servername localhost 8080. meu firewal esta ativado e meu roteador esta com a porta 8080 aberta. uso um roteador INTELBRAS WRN300. Mas nao entra quando acesso "meuip:8080". alhuem pode me ajudar a resolver esse problema!
[image: roteador]

Comment: Bem-vindo, você deve liberar a porta no firewall. Qual erro está retornando quando você tenta acessar?

Comment: apenas aparece que nao é possivel acessar

Comment: qual firewal ? o do windows ou do roteador?

Comment: configurei no firewal.    porta: 8080 e endereço ip ?

Comment: do Windows porque também bloqueia

Comment: como fazer esta etapa?